# Congruence mod p involving a product

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, products

Let $p$ be a prime, $p\equiv 3$ mod $4$. Numerically it appears that
$$
\prod_{n=1}^{p-1}\left(1+n^2\right)\equiv 4\mod p.
$$
How can one prove this? For $p\equiv 1$ mod $4$, the product is $0$ mod $p$ because $-1$ is a quadratic residue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's work over the finite field $\Bbb F_p$ with $p\equiv3\pmod 4$. One can adjoin
$i$ to this with $i^2=-1$ to get the finite field $k=\Bbb F_{p^2}$. Your product
is
$$\prod_{n=1}^{p-1}(n^2+1)=\prod_{n=1}^{p-1}(n-i)(n+i)=f(i)f(-i)$$
where
$$f(X)=\prod_{n=1}^{p-1}(X+n)=X^{p-1}-1$$
(we are working in characteristic $p$).
Then
$$f(i)=-1-1=-2.$$
Likewise, $f(-i)=-2$ and so the original product is $4$.